# adb get full path by mask on android

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, subprocess, adb

How I'm can get full path if I haven't name of file? Python3.
I use this:

```
previous_v = ("/sdcard/AppPackage/old_version/" +
str(subprocess.check_call(["adb", "shell", "ls", "/sdcard/AppPackage/old_version/"]))[0])
```

but it's cumbersome

Comment: You might be interested in using the Google's official [Python ADB package](https://github.com/google/python-adb)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're running this Python code on the Android device.

```
import os
BASE_DIR = '/sdcard/AppPackage/old_version'
previous_v = BASE_DIR + '/' + os.listdir(BASE_DIR)[0]
```

This might simplify your code, but beware: Just using the first file in a list of files can lead to undesired effects, when there are more than one file in the given directory. You might also want to check if there is a file present at all.

---

**Edit**: Code extended by matching for a string that must appear in the filename and by error handling when no file could be found.

```
import os

BASE_DIR = '/sdcard/AppPackage/old_version'
FILENAME_PATTERN = 'my_great_app'

filenames = os.listdir(BASE_DIR)
filenames = [fn for fn in filenames if fn.contains(FILENAME_PATTERN)]

if not filenames:
    raise FileNotFoundError('No old version found!')

previous_v = BASE_DIR + '/' + os.listdir(BASE_DIR)[0]
```

Comment: I know but that might be only one file.  I want shorten code)